# Magento Transactional Emails get saved incorrectly and changed when saving from Admin (CMS).

Tags: mysql, json, magento, amazon-web-services, transactional-email

## Magento Transactional Emails (from Admin)

How do I get Magento to save the templates exactly how they are entered in Admin? For me it drops **\** that escape characters in the code making it impossible for Magneto to re-open the template once its saved.

## Example:

After creating or loading a new template in admin, I save the cms page with code like this:

```
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",
"htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()":"Customer Name",
"var store.getFrontendName()":"Store Name",
"store url=\"customer/account/\"":"Customer Account Url",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')":"Order Created At (datetime)",
"var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')":"Billing Address",
"var payment_html":"Payment Details",
"var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order":"Order Items Grid",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note"}
```

Then after I try to re-open it, I get an error message and Magento refuses to even preview let alone edit the template.

> There has been an error processing your request The error has been
>   logged and we will review it's contents. Clear your cookies for
>   pumpunderwear.* and please re-try. If you keep seeing this again and
>   again, come back later and we should have this fixed.  Decoding
>   failed: Syntax error

## Trace:

```
#0 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(590): Zend_Json::decode('{"store url="""...')
#1 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(604): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->_parseVariablesString('{"store url="""...')
#2 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Email/Template/Edit/Form.php(186): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->getVariablesOptionArray(true)
#3 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Email/Template/Edit/Form.php(112): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Email_Template_Edit_Form->getVariables()
#4 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Email_Template_Edit_Form->_prepareForm()
#5 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#6 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('form', true)
#8 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Email/Template/Edit.php(235): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('form')
#9 /web/store/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/email/template/edit.phtml(108): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Email_Template_Edit->getFormHtml()
#10 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/www.pu...')
#11 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#12 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#17 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#19 /web/store/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#20 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/www.pu...')
#21 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#22 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#27 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Email/TemplateController.php(109): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#28 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_Email_TemplateController->editAction()
#29 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#30 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 /web/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#32 /web/store/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#33 /web/store/index.php(135): Mage::run('', 'store')
#34 {main}
```

#### It seems to be a problem decoding the store URL variable

```
Zend_Json::decode('{"store url="""...')
```

When I check the database, I see that it has been saved differently then how I had saved it in Admin.  It no longer has the quotes escaped and is missing a few slashes and other formatting changes. It now looks like this:

```
{"store url=""":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",
"htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()":"Customer Name",
"var store.getFrontendName()":"Store Name",
"store url="customer/account/"":"Customer Account Url",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')":"Order Created At (datetime)",
"var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')":"Billing Address",
"var payment_html":"Payment Details",
"var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order":"Order Items Grid",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note"}
```

I changed it in the database directly, and then I was able to open the template again in admin, but after I save it, the same thing happens. What can I do to have it keep the forward slashes infront of the quotes etc.?

### Is this a Magento code issue or a server/database encoding issue?

## Thanks!!

- Server is Nginx for static content
- Apache2 for dynamic.
- Web server on AWS EC2
- DB is separate server AWS EC2
- php 5.5.30
- mysql 5.6.25